# Merging nested dictionaries by keys preserving different values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I have two list of nested dictionaries with the same keys, but different values:

```
d1 = {
    'distilled ': [{'water': '45'}, {'vodka': '9'}, {'vinegar': '7'}, {'beer': '6'}, {'alcohol': '5'}, {'whiskey': '5'}],
    'planted': [{'tree': '30'}, {'seed': '28'}, {'flower': '20'}, {'plant': '7'}, {'bomb': '4'}, {'garden': '2'}]
}
```

and

```
d2 = {
    'distilled  ': [{'water': '14'}, {'vinegar': '9'}, {'wine': '8'}, {'alcohol': '8'}, {'liquid': '7'}, {'whiskey': '6'}, {'beer': '5'}], 
    'planted ': [{'flower': '28'}, {'tree': '18'}, {'seed': '9'}, {'vegetable': '4'}, {'bush': '3'}, {'grass': '3'}, {'garden': '3'}]
}
```

I want to merge them in a way that preserves the values and merges only the keys in the nested dictionaries. So that the outcome would look like:

```
{
    'distilled ': [('water', '45', '14'), ('vodka', '9'), ('vinegar', '7', '9'), ('beer', '6', '5'), ('alcohol',  '5'), ('whiskey', '5'), ('wine', '8')], 
    'planted': [('tree', '30', '18'), ('seed', '28', '9'), ('flower', '20', '7'), ('plant', '7'), ('bomb', '4'), ('garden', '2', '3')]
}
```

I tried merging the two using:

```
d_merged = { k: [ d1[k], d2_to_compare[k] ] for k in d1 }
```

but the in the outcome only the values of the first dictionary are presented, obviously. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance.

I am not sure which way to take from here. Would really appreciate any suggestions! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gosh, still sticking to the list-of-dictionaries-with-only-one-key-each structure? That makes this specific task unnecessarily more difficult.

Comment: All your dictionaries are **separate objects**, so you cannot just enumerate all their keys and look up the keys in the other list of dictionaries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. Unfortunately this is the case because they come from different data bases, I want to merge them somehow without loosing information. I did not choose to make them separate objects. :(

Answer (score 0):

dict only has one key-value pair is not a good idea, but anyway, we can work out like this:

```
d1 = {
    'distilled': [{'water': '45'}, {'vodka': '9'}, {'vinegar': '7'}, {'beer': '6'},        {'alcohol': '5'}, {'whiskey': '5'}],
    'planted': [{'tree': '30'}, {'seed': '28'}, {'flower': '20'}, {'plant': '7'}, {'bomb': '4'}, {'garden': '2'}]
}

d2 = {
    'distilled': [{'water': '14'}, {'vinegar': '9'}, {'wine': '8'}, {'alcohol': '8'},   {'liquid': '7'}, {'whiskey': '6'}, {'beer': '5'}],
    'planted': [{'flower': '28'}, {'tree': '18'}, {'seed': '9'}, {'vegetable': '4'}, {'bush': '3'}, {'grass': '3'}, {'garden': '3'}]
}

d3 = {}

for k, v in d1.items():
    k1 = dict([d.items()[0] for d in d1[k]])
    k2 = dict([d.items()[0] for d in d2[k]])
    ret = []
    for d in (set(k1.keys()) | set(k2.keys())):
        ret.append((d, k1.get(d), k2.get(d)))
    d3[k] = ret

print d3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am  getting the error message: `k1 = dict([d.items()[0] for d in dic1_to_compare[k]])
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`, what do you think can be causing this?

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: Sorry for taking long to get to you! Is is Python 3.2.